# How to verify my ultrasound transducer is working?

Tags: ultrasound

Hi I am fairly new to electronics equipment and over the past weeks have been setting up an ultrasound device to simulate traumatic brain injuries in samples at the lab I work at.

My setup consists of a SiglentSDG810 waveform generator connected to a Tekbox TBHDR1 RF amplifier which then connects to the ultrasound transducer.  My transducer also has a built in hydrophone that connects directly to an older analog Tenma oscilloscope.

The transducer is calibrated to 500kHz and the amplifier has a gain of +24dbm at that frequency so I have been sending 1.2Vpp sine waves at 500khz through the system.  On the oscilloscope which is connected to the hydrophone I am receiving a 1.2Vpp sine wave,  is this something to be expected from a setup like this.  Or is there another way to more easily verify my transducer is producing ultrasound.

There may be some info missing in my question but I do have calibration data for everything from the manufacturers.

How do I verify my ultrasound transducer is working?

Comment: Some transducers work in both directions, I mean: 1) electrical signal => soundwaves but also 2) soundwaves => electrical signal. Depending on the type you might be able to use a transducer as a microphone as well. Unfortunately you mention nothing about the transducer you're using.

Comment: See if you can compare the phase of TX and RX. The phase shifts upon the distance between TX & RX.

Comment: When you say you want to confirm if it's working, do you mean making sure that x Vrms applied across your transducer will result in almost y dB in 1m, or do you want to check if it's working at all? if the latter, there are ultrasonic modules which can be easily used to measure distance, maybe the transducer itself does that as well? worth checking

Comment: Do you have a transducer data sheet you  can link to?

Comment: Maybe a good test to verify the operation of the US transducer. Take a metal plate (reflective in any case) and put it in front of the transducer. Measure or view the voltage applied directly to the transducer. In "principle", the voltage should vary (in amplitude and in phase ?, if we have a reference ...) when we move the plate in front of the transducer through the change of 'mechanic impedance'.

Comment: I would recommend connecting it to a VNA (like the NanoVNA) to check if you are getting its impulse reponse.